# SpringBoot listening to a Redis Stream: How to stop reconnection attempts after N fails

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am building a SpringBoot Application that listen to a Redis Stream using an [Imperative StreamMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/reference/redis/redis-streams.html#imperative-streammessagelistenercontainer).

When the connection with the redis server fails, I would like to stop trying to reconnect after N failed tries. How can I achieve that?

The subscription and start of the StreamMessageListenerContainer are implemented like that:

```
@Bean
public Subscription subscription(
    RedisConnectionFactory factory,
    StreamListener<String, ObjectRecord<String, String>> listener
) throws UnknownHostException {
    var errorHandler = new RedisErrorHandler();

    var options = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions
        .builder()
        .targetType(String.class)
        .errorHandler(errorHandler)
        .build();

    var container = StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(factory, options);
    errorHandler.setContainer(container);

    var subscription = container.receiveAutoAck(
        Consumer.from(streamKey, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()),
        StreamOffset.create(streamKey, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()),
        listener
    );

    container.start();

    return subscription;
}
```

I also tried to create a custom ErrorHandler to stop the container but it does not work:

```
class RedisErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private StreamMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container;

    public void setContainer(StreamMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        log.error("An error occurred while trying to access redis server: " + t.getMessage());
        container.stop();
    }
}
```

If I start the SpringBoot app and stop the redis server I could still see the reconnect attempts on the console:

```
2024-02-06 15:53:56.902  WARN 13468 --- [ioEventLoop-4-1] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Cannot reconnect to [127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:6379]: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:6379
2024-02-06 15:54:05.101  INFO 13468 --- [xecutorLoop-1-2] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Reconnecting, last destination was 127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:6379
2024-02-06 15:54:05.105  WARN 13468 --- [ioEventLoop-4-2] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Cannot reconnect to [127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:6379]: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:6379
2024-02-06 15:54:21.500  INFO 13468 --- [xecutorLoop-1-4] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Reconnecting, last destination was 127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:6379
```

I took a look at the ConnectionWatchdog class and it seems there is a **ReconnectionHandler** that could do the trick but I have no idea how to access it.